# problema en la plantilla de texto en pdf

Tags: pdf

tengo un problema y estoy atascado, haber si me puedes ayudar por favor.
necesito hacer una plantilla en pdf para poner los datos de una matricula, el formato es de 52 x 11 cm lo intento hacer con iText 7
pero cuando empiezo ha agrandarlo al fina no me muestra los números. y necesitaria tambien pone cada número con una seoaración determindada. consigo poner la plantilla pero cuando agrando la font no me deja agrandarlo tanto y me desaparece
agradezco toda la ayuda posible
utilizo fontsize
gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: necesito hacer un programa en java que yo ponga el número de una matricula creando un PDF, en tamaño din4 o din3 no hay problema con rectangle y la propiedad de fontSize le pongo el tamaño de la plantilla que es 52 por 11 cm, pero necesito que en esa plantilla tienen que salir la numeración y las letras de la matricula con unas medidas y unos espacios concretos. el problema es que creo la plantilla con

Comment: necesito hacer un programa en java que yo ponga el número de una matricula creando un PDF, en tamaño din4 o din3 no hay problema con rectangle y la propiedad de fontSize le pongo el tamaño de la plantilla que es 52 por 11 cm, pero necesito que en esa plantilla tienen que salir la numeración y las letras de la matricula con unas medidas y unos espacios concretos. el problema es que creo la plantilla con      variable.           Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(1474, 315f); //ancho y alto
                                                       gracias

Comment: Document docu = new Document(pageSize);                                                          luego le pongo el texto                                                                                           fuente.setFontSize(480);              pero en este caso no se centra en el rectangle, y si voy pasando hacia la derecha no me muestra las letras, me las recorta. espero puedan ayudarme. no se si hay otra libreria que lo pueda hacer. estoy usando iText 7.